# How to login to Azure account from command line in a bash script

Tags: bash, syntax, azure-cli

I have created a bash script as I want to Start and Stop Virtual machines by a Jenkins Job. The content of script is below

## !/bin/bash

```
set -x


applicationId = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
tenantID="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
password = "jenkins"
    
az login --service-principal --username "${applicationId}" --password "{$password}" --tenant "{tenantID}"

export resource_group=rg_networking
# declare an array variable
declare -a host_list=("<Array of Host Space sepperated>")

## now loop through the above array
for i in "${host_list[@]}"
do
   echo "Stopping Virtual Machine $i"
   az vm stop --name "${i}" --resource-group "${resource_group}"
done

exit 0
```

And the error message I get when I run the Jenkins job is below:

```
Get Token request returned http error: 400 and server response: {"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"AADSTS90002: Requested tenant identifier '{tenantid}' is not valid and not valid external domain format\r\nTrace ID: 1bb4c96a-c26c-48a3-b502-7d8b17b90800\r\nCorrelation ID: 2b01e6aa-0fd6-4a52-878b-f829d5d02152\r\nTimestamp: 2018-11-06 23:42:36Z","error_codes":[90002],"timestamp":"2018-11-06 23:42:36Z","trace_id":"1bb4c96a-c26c-48a3-b502-7d8b17b90800","correlation_id":"2b01e6aa-0fd6-4a52-878b-f829d5d02152"}
```

and also the below erro after every az stop vm stement ix executed.

```
ERROR: Please run 'az login' to setup account.
```

Unable to understand what is the problem?

Can anyone assist me please?

Thanks

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first error was caused by this part, you missed the `$` in your command.

```
az login --service-principal --username "${applicationId}" --password "{$password}" --tenant "{tenantID}"
```

Try the command below, it works fine on my side.

```
az login --service-principal --username "${applicationId}" --password "${password}" --tenant "${tenantID}"
```

[image]

After you logging in, the `ERROR: Please run 'az login' to setup account.` error will also be fixed.

Comment: Cyrus , Thanks for the pointer! It shall be very useful.

Joy, Thanks for that, it is working now. Need to be more attentive next time.

Comment: WARNING - ERROR: Please run 'az account set' to select active account. After following the above steps i get this error once a while. Could you guide me how to fix this ?